# Paypal IPN suddenly just stopped sending back item_number POST var

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Causing havoc on the site. Full dump of all post vars during the notify callback doesn't show the item_number variable at all. But it was sent. 
Has something happened with IPN that I missed?

Comment: You say "it was sent" but this needs to be verified.  I have never seen an instance where item details were included with the payment request but were not included in IPN.  Are you using a Standard payment button?  Express Checkout APIs, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had this problem. The issue is that earlier today, without notice, Paypal have started sending this as item_number1 (note the suffix '1'). This surely must be a bug, because a Google search suggests this behaviour is only supposed to trigger for shopping cart checkouts, and in that case it would be item_number_1 (note the suffix '_1').

If this situation continues, the solution is to update your scripts to read from item_number1, as well as item_number. Paypal may revert this behaviour, if it is a bug (which presumably it is). It might be wise to make them also check for item_number_1, in case they make a change to treat the checkout as a shopping cart in future.

Comment: It looks like Paypal have fixed this - my sites are receiving 'item_number'  again, but I have implemented a check for the other two forms above in case of a future repetition of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like item_number is now item_number1, which is creating some issues.